# Simple Socket example issue in Android

Tags: android, sockets

Can anyone let me know what is wrong in the below code.. Why is it not executing the while loop block?
I have the necessary permissions in the manifest file.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

static TextView t;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    NetConnect th=new NetConnect();
    th.start();
}
public class NetConnect extends Thread {
    public void run(){
        try{
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){public void run(){t.append("Thread start...");}});
            Socket client = new Socket("time-b.nist.gov", 13);
            BufferedReader in =new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            String str;
            while((str=in.readLine())!=null)
                t.append(str);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.e("Internet:",e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error in the LogCat? I imagine an exception is being thrown.

Comment: BTW You should close the BufferedReader and the socket.

Comment: Closing part is ok Alejandro.. I need to close.. there is no error, nothing printed in LogCat

Comment: when the URL is called through browser it shows **Connection refused: time-b.nist.gov:80**. Kindly check that

Comment: If "there is no error, nothing printed in LogCat", then the server "time-b.nist.gov" is simply not returning anything or even refusing connection, as @Sankar said. Try with other servers to check if it's really a problem with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a problem with "time-b.nist.gov". I tried the following simple socket example in a java project (to simplify against creating an Android project):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class TestSocketClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hostname = "time-b.nist.gov";

        try {
            Socket theSocket = new Socket(hostname, 13);
            InputStream timeStream = theSocket.getInputStream();
            StringBuffer time = new StringBuffer();
            int c;
            while ((c = timeStream.read()) != -1)
                time.append((char) c);
            String timeString = time.toString().trim();
            System.out.println("It is " + timeString + " at " + hostname);
        } // end try
        catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Nothing returned if `String hostname = "time-b.nist.gov";`:

> It is  at time-b.nist.gov

but if I change it to `String hostname = "time.nist.gov";` I get:

> It is 56438 13-05-26 11:49:57 50 0 0 809.9 UTC(NIST) * at
>   time.nist.gov